# Cocos2d-x 3.0 , setup the debug environment and remove the red marks in eclipse

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, eclipse-cdt, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am struggling with this issue since last week.

I still can’t figure out where is the error.

My code is compiling perfect if I restart the eclipse. but, when I edit the c++ file it shows red marks in eclipse. and I get error that “Your project contains error(s), please fix it before running it.”

I have also used this link to setup and get it working. http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Please help me setup the debug environment and remove the red marks in my eclipse.

P.S.

development platform : win 8.1

I'm using:

cocos2d-x-3.0rc1 C++.

adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321

android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64

apache-ant-1.9.3-bin

Pythone2.7

Comment: Disable syntax and semantic errors in Code Analysis in Project Properties.

Comment: Like this I can't see even the real errors.

Comment: Check I have added answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup all includes path correctly in your project properties.

[image]

In my case my project location is a directory inside `D:/cocos2dx-2.2.2/projects/MyGame/pro.android` and that is why I have used variable `${PARENT-3-PROJECT_LOC}` variable.

Comment: Thank you! it worked fine, but how can I detect errors in this case?

Comment: You don't need to turn off syntax and semantic errors in that case.